# How to insert the values of a function every nth row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a function in Excel that calculates the average of some numbers 
`=AVERAGE(I1:I36)` for example.

The thing is, I need to paste this function every 49 rows, instead of counting the rows manually then copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in VBA (avoiding blank formulae) you could try this:

*Enters formulas from A1 to A50000 every 9 rows*

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(50000, "A"))
rng1.FormulaR1C1 = Application.Evaluate("=IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A50000),49)=0,""=AVERAGE(RC9:R[35]C9)"","""")")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),49)=0,AVERAGE($I$1:$I$36),"")
```

If you save in c1 the starting row and in c2 the frequency of the formula, it should look like

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-$c$1+$c$2,$c$2)=0,AVERAGE($I$1:$I$36),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Decision 1**

Use `=IF(MOD((ROW()-ROW($I$1)),49)=0;AVERAGE(I1:I36);"")`
Pro: pure formula, without macros.
Cons: you have to use entire column for it, excessive calculations (btw ROW() function is not efficient, so it would be better to spend another column for row number).

**Decision 2**

Just select cell with a formula and 48 empty cells, press "Copy", then select entire range and press "Paste".

Comment: My excel skill are poor, i created a column right to it, which is J, and selected entire J column and pasted your function, and didnt work, so then i changed then $I to $J and still no use.

Comment: Sherif, You should put cell references between '$' to properly copy the formula